# Does it provide any benefits to simultaneously use __attribute__ ((pure)) and static inline?

Tags: c, performance, gcc, compiler-optimization

I am optimizing a c program and I would like to know if it does make any sense to use `__attribute__ ((pure))` and `static inline` both in the same function declaration?

Comment: Do you mean `static __attribute__((pure))` ?

Comment: It could be useful in principle - if for some reason the compiler is unable to inline some call to the function, it will still know that it is pure and that redundant calls can be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three attributes are orthogonal to each other:

- `static` says that function is not used outside of compilation unit so it won't be exported and won't pollute external namespace
- `inline` increases the chance that function is inlined
- `pure` tells compiler that function does not have side effects so if inlining fails compiler will still be able to optimize code around function call more aggressively

So none of them is a substitute to another and they should be used simultaneously.